# Invariance of differential equation under parameter shift

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading Arnold's "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" and there he mentions that the following differential equation is useful in physics.
$$ \ddot{x} = F(x, \dot{x}, t) $$

Here, dots are derivatives with respect to the parameter $t$ and $x$ is assumed to be function $t \mapsto x(t)$. In the book he mentions that if $x = \phi(t)$ is a solution to this equation and if for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $x = \phi(t+s)$  is also a solution then the previous differential equation can be written in the following way.

$$ \ddot{x} = F(x, \dot{x}) $$

Can you please help me to understand how to conclude that? Also, I am not really sure I understand the assumption because let us assume that we consider the differential equation defined for parameter values being the whole real line. Then, if we assume that the differential equation is unique, doesn't that necessarily imply that it is always true that if $x = \phi (t)$ is solution then $x = \phi(t+s)$ is a solution? My intuitive reasoning is that I solve equation and have unique solution $x = \phi(t)$. But because I am just shifting the parameter I just have shifted initial values but because they are still on the solution and all derivatives at this point are the same as for the original solution then this should be solution as well.

What have I tried so far:

I think the notation for the differential equation just means the following. Assume that $x : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^N$. Consider $A_x : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{2N+1}$ defined by $A_x: t \mapsto (x(t), \dot{x}(t), t)$. Then we say that:

$$ \ddot{x}(t) = (F \circ A)(t) $$

And this is supposed to be true for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Assume that $x = \phi(t)$ is a solution. That means that the following equation is true for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$ \ddot{\phi}(t) = (F \circ A_{\phi})(t) $$

Now consider new function $B: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $B: t \mapsto t+s$. Then we assume that $x(t)= (\phi \circ B)(t)$ is also a solution. That means the following.

$$ \ddot{(\phi \circ B)}(t) = (F \circ A_{\phi \circ B})(t) $$

By the chain rule and the fact that $\dot{B}(t) = 1$ we have the following.

$$ (\ddot{\phi}\circ B)(t) = F(\phi \circ B, \dot{\phi} \circ B, B^{-1} \circ B) (t)$$

I am not sure what to do next.

Also, I would really appreciate if someone can show me an example of $F$ where $x=\phi(t)$ is a solution but $x = \phi(t+s)$ is not.

Comment: For an extremely simple example, take $\ddot{x}(t)=6t$. Then $x(t)=t^3$ is a solution, but $x(t)=(t+1)^3$ is not.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for the comment! But in your case, how do your initial conditions shift? I am not sure how did you choose integration constants.

Comment: If you want to think of this in terms of initial conditions, $x(t)=t^3$ is the solution of $\ddot x=6t$ with $x(0)=\dot x(0)=0$. But if you start with **the same initial conditions at another time**, say $t=1$ so that the equation is $\ddot x=6t$ with $x(1)=\dot x(1)=0$, then the solution is $x(t)=t^3-3t+2$, which is **not** just a time-shift of the first solution (that would have been $x(t)=(t-1)^3$). Since the ODE itself contains the variable $t$ explicitly, **it makes a difference at what time you start**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi_s(t)=\phi(s+t)$ is also a solution, then
$$
\ddot\phi_s(t)=F(\phi_s(t),\dot\phi_s(t),t).\\
$$
Inserting the construction of $\phi_s$ at $t=t_0-s$ one gets
$$
\ddot\phi(t_0)=F(\phi(t_0),\dot\phi(t_0), t_0-s).
$$
At the same time $\phi$ is a solution, so that also
$$
\ddot\phi(t_0)=F(\phi(t_0),\dot\phi(t_0), t_0).
$$
This means that $F(x,\dot x,t)$ has the same value for all $t$, thus is independent of $t$.